# What are some good methods for detecting movement using a camera? (opencv)

Tags: python, opencv

I am looking for some methods for detecting movement. I've tried two of them. One method is to have background frame that has been set on program start and other frames are compared (threshold) to that background frame. Other method is to compare current frame (let's call that frame A) with frame-1 (frame before A). None of these methods are great. I want to know other methods that work better.

Comment: What sort of movement? Those two algorithms are basic and will work for simple motion detection.

Comment: Yes, what kind of movement? and why, in your case, it does not work great ?

Comment: @Science_Fiction: They will work for simple motion detection. But for example one I need to "reset" that background image each time and that's bothering me, and for example two if that object that was moving suddenly slows or stops it would't be detected on other frames.

Comment: What you can also do is compare two frame accumulators (e.g. accumulateWeighted with with different alphas )... But it is hard to answer without knowing the type of noise and movement.

Comment: @Science_Fiction: I am not expert in openCV or motion detection. Could you give me some examples of types of movement so I could choose one that I think I am looking for? Basically, this is what I am trying to achieve. I want to track (and count) cars and people that are passing through my street (Why? Because I am trying to learn new stuff and that looks fun thing to make). If that car stops he wouldn't be seen on other frames using that 2nd method. If there's wind and turns my cam, I would get totally wrong results. (Help!)

Comment: You've started with a pretty tough project in the realms of image processing if you are just starting out. Maybe try doing some blob analysis/detection for the vehicles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out:

1. [Motion detection using Python](http://bogdanmarian.com/motion/)
2. [Motion tracking Python](http://derek.simkowiak.net/motion-tracking-with-python/)

Answer (score 1):

[Lucas-Kande](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Kanade_method) method is something worth looking at.

Answer (score 1):

Please go through the book **Learning OpenCV: Computer Vision with the OpenCV Library**

It has theory as well as example codes.